# "Einen guten Rutsch" in Gebärdensprache

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Im Fernsehen habe ich einen Gebärdendolmetscher gesehen, der "einen guten Rutsch" mit einer Geste begleitete, die aussah, als ob die rechte Hand eine Rutschbahn hinunterrutscht. Ist diese Interpretation richtig? Werden in der deutschen Gebärdensprache das Rutschen auf der Rutschbahn und der gute Rutsch mit  derselben Gebärde dargestellt?

Comment: Die Gebärdensprache ist eine eigenständige Sprache. Daher sind Fragen dazu vermutlich *off-topic*

Comment: Es gibt nicht nur eine Gebärdensprache, die deutsche Gebärdensprache unterscheidet sich von der anderer Nationen. Aber wir können das gerne auf Meta diskutieren.

Comment: Frage auf Meta: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1440/ist-deutsche-geb%c3%a4rdensprache-on-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nein, die Rutschbahn/Rutschen und "Guten Rutsch" bestehen nicht aus derselben Gebärde. **Aber**: Die Gebärde für Rutsche steckt im Wunsch drin.

Dieses Video schlüsselt die Gebärde auf: *Guten* wird als ein bekanntes OK-Handzeichen dargestellt und *Rutsch* als die von dir beschriebene Rutschbewegung.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqtTd_C8Q9c

Alternatives Video:
https://www.mdr.de/barrierefreiheit/gebaerdensprache/video-72254.html

Und schließlich hier noch eine Art Gebärdenlexikon in der das Wort für Rutsche dargestellt wird, das dem gezeigten entspricht. Ob es wichtig ist, ob die Hand über oder unter der anderen "durchrutscht" kann vielleicht jemand weiteres beantworten.
https://gebaerdenlernen.de/index.php?article_id=91